# How to store a JSON string as entity's attribute

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm making a game (trying...) like Risk for college with Spring MVC. I'm using JPA and I need to save the state of the game (whose player turn is, units in countries,etc.)  in a String field coded with JSON, and that's what's driving me crazy.
First, I create the game with other information (id, user's owner, state...) and when It starts for the first time I want to generate the JSON and set it to the entity and save it. I tried with entityManager.merge(game) but when I look at the DB the JSON field is null. I tried to make namedquery and nativequery but at the JSON string have " it's a mess.
Any ideas why it's not saving with merge?
The code is something like:

HomeController.class

```
public String getGame(@PathVariable("idGame") long idGame,
        Model model) throws IOException {           
        Game g = GameDao.getGame(idGame);
        if  (g.getJson == null) {
            g.initializeGame(); // it sets the json attribute
            GameDao.update(entityManager, g);
        }
}
```

GameDAO.class

```
@Transactional
public static Game update(EntityManager entityManager, Game g) {
    try {       
        entityManager.merge(g); // if I debug here g has the json attribute setted
        return entityManager.find(Game.class, g.getId()); // the game object that's returned hasn't the json field setted
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is the repo https://github.com/alvardsoler/reinvasion but it's the most in Spanish. It's for september exams and I don't have too much time so I want to do it very sketchy first, and then if I have time I'll do it good. If I can't save the JSON info in the DB I will save it in a file in the server with the id of the game or something like that.

Comment: Already tried the GSON library? We used that in a similar situation and it worked perfectly: https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: @Phiwa In what way? I used it to create the JSON string Gson gson = new Gson(); this.json = gson.toJson(jp, JuegoPartida.class); (in initializeGame()).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I make the update with createNativeQuery:

```
Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("update Game g SET   g.json=:json where g.id=:id");
q.setParameter("json", g.getJson());
q.setParameter("id", g.getId());
q.executeUpdate();
```

And added @Transactional in the GameDAO's method and in the HomeController method...

Answer (score 0):

It is rather easy using the library GSON (jsonString ):

```
// Create the JSON string like this first

MyObject yourObject = /* Create an object here */;
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonString = gson.toJson(yourObject);


// Create an object from the JSON string like this afterwards
MyObject newObject = gson.fromJson(jsonString , MyObject.class);
```

Comment: That's what I do. The problem is when I want to store in the DB. The JSON String is good, when I send it to the client I can manipulate it with Javascript and so on. See https://github.com/alvardsoler/reinvasion/blob/master/src/main/java/es/ucm/reinvasion/model/Partida.java line 103

Comment: Oh, you mean you just got a problem with the " and ' in the string? You could escape thos characters before saving to the database to avoid those problems.

Comment: Yes. I suppose this is the problem. I tried with string.replace("\"", "\\\""); but it doesn't work... You mean replace every " in the JSON String with \", no?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: If you use a PreparedStatement you should not have a problem, but using \" should work as well, so I'm a bit confused this causes problems in your case.

Comment: I'm leaving work now and I'll try PreparedStatment when I arrive home and update with the stack trace of the Exception if it throws any... Thx a lot!

Comment: I've found the problem... two fixs and now it works! The big one was @Transactional tag... thx for your help!